# jest - react - mocked geolocation inside useEffect in hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

how would you test a hook that is using  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` method (mocked it already based on this: https://newdevzone.com/posts/how-to-mock-navigatorgeolocation-in-a-react-jest-test) in `useEffect`?
I can't see the way how to wait for result as upon calling the function it does not return anything and returned data are processed in passed callback. found some hackish solution that works when run debug using jest runner vsc extension, but does not for regular test run.

the hook:

```
const useGeolocation = () => {
  const [coords, setCoords] = useState<GeolocationCoordinates>();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      setCoords(position.coords);
    });
  }, []);

  return coords;
};
```

test:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';

it('should return non-empty coords', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useGeolocation());

    // MISSING CODE

    expect(result.current).not.toBe(undefined);
});
```

I'll be happy for any idea leading to solution so I don't need to give up on unit testing once again :slight_smile:

Comment: Did you try using the `waitFor` function in the testing library?  It will poll for an expectation for some period of time until it passes or fails on timeout.  Personal opinion:  giving up on unit testing will limit your growth and capacity as a developer.  It can be extraordinarily hard, but it requires you learn about and understand the systems you work with and leads to top notch code.

Comment: does not work unfortunately :( I've obviously gone through https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/ but it never came to my mind it could be what I was looking for - a replacement of `waitForNextUpdate` from the `@testing-library/react-hooks`

Comment: about the giving up on unit testing - agree with you about the growth and capacity, however usually it takes me more time to write down and maintain all tests instead of finalizing a small project within no time and as I'm a bit perfectionist I usually bump into something unexplored and burn loads of time trying to solve it - but defo improves my skills

Comment: strangely it works when i debug test using jest runner vsc extension tho -_-

Comment: There's asynchronous code running and it's likely vsc is picking it up late enough it's passes.  You should use the `waitFor` or some other equivalent mechanism in those situations to be consistent

Comment: updated mocks so there's no promise and it passes, thanks for the motivation to not give up :)

Comment: If the real equivalent is returning a promise, I'd keep mock with a promise and use the `waitFor`.  It's a little more ugly, but if you wanted to make a change in the future where you, say, tack on a `then` in the production code your tests can stay the same.

Comment: it's not actually, as I said in the OP: it does not return anything and returned data are processed in passed callback